# It seems like oraclized takes way more than $0.05

Tags: gas, oracles, fees

When a TX for a random number like such: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x54fa389796fea546ac6562bec7cfe4b0daca1b744920a38a0e85036b07a1e0ee

It says that 0.004 ehter was send to oraclized and it is not put back in my contract, this is worth way more that the $0.05 that is in Oraclized price tables.. How/when does the ETH come back?

Comment: It does not come back. How oraclize prices their service is up to them